# 2-legged OAuth in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, oauth, 2-legged

I am developing a service to get data from Echo System using their Scheduling API.

Echo System Scheduling API requires each request to be signed by OAuth(2-legged).
I have generated the request URL but I am getting "I/O Exception: Name in certificate" Error.

Echo System uses https, so i am thinking it might be the cause but i am not sure.

Any comments

Comment: Do they have a cert from a trusted source, or is it self-signed?

Comment: I have the cert from Echo System

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are doing the signature correctly.  Signatures can be real tricky.  You'll need to make encoding is being done to the different RFC spec requirements that it needs (for example, Twitter uses the RFC 3986 spec) and really there's no language that will do this outright (including ColdFusion), you'll need to create a function to do it.  Also, make sure you are using the right type of encryption (oAuth specifies many different type of encryption possibilities, but different services use whatever they want: all of them, or only one of them, etc. etc.).  Make sure the elements of your unencoded signature are in lexicographical order (generally, this means fields in ABC order).

Read the documentation very carefully.  Anything dealing with oAuth gets very specific.  Also, don't be afraid to do a lot of trial-and-error kinds of things.  Sometimes, you'll just find the right combination that makes it all work.  Good luck!

Comment: This answer is so true... and that's exactly why OAuth is a pain to implement.